# Find good smoothing spline factor

Tags: curve-fitting, splines, smoothing

I'd like an automatic way to find the "best" smoothing factor `s` for a spline fit to a given set of data points. Here's a sample visualization of some data and the fit splines for various s values:

[image]

In this case, clearly `s=2` (and at a lesser degree `s=1`) is not a good fit. On the other hand `s=0.5` fits the data almost as good as `s=0.1` but with less than half the number of knots and thus is less susceptible to overfitting. So my question is, what's a robust method to determine the "optimal", or at least a good enough `s` to fit the data?

Comment: You might consider cross-validation approaches.

Comment: Are you working in any particular programming language? Also, what type of spline are you working with?

Comment: I'm using scipy's [UnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html)

Comment: If you iterate over a range of smoothing factors, each time calculating R-squared (R2) as "R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)" (this would run quickly) and then plot smoothing factor vs. R-squared, you should be able to see where the approximate optimal smoothing factor is on that plot. This is easy to program and might be worth a try as it is simple to do. For a numpy array named X, the variance is X.var() so the R-squared calculation becomes trivial with numpy.

Comment: Wow, the content in the [scipy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html) is incorrect. This is certainly **not** a [**smoothing spline**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline). Could you post the data? I would like to provide at least a clean R solution.

Comment: @Jim, I just ran several tests, and the scipy spline smoothing is not working as I thought - not at all. My tests were as I had suggested, to iterate over a range of smoothing factors for different spline orders and plot the resulting R-squared vs. smoothing factor -yea, it stinketh.This is a very nice catch, well done.

Comment: @Jim thanks for looking into it. I uploaded a sample dataset similar to the original one [here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/e78a2c739a7da3db534cf52fed47ce56/binned_wbr_avg.csv).

Answer (score 1):

*What is a smoothing spline?*

The [Wikipedia article on smoothing splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline) does a good job in explaining that. To recap, given a set of data points, $\{ (x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^n \}$, a smoothing spline is a solution to the interpolation problem:

$$\underset{f}{\arg\min} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - f(x_i))^2 + \lambda \int_{x_{(1)}}^{x_{(n)}} f''(x)^2 dx,$$

with $f$ constrained to be piecewise cubic between different $x_i$. The first part measures the goodness of fit of such an $f$ to the observed data. The second part is a penalty term for the wiggliness (non-smoothness) of $f$.

Leaving it to us to find a good trade-off between fit and smoothness by means of $\lambda$.

---

*Smoothing splines in R*

Luckily R has the [`splines`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/splines/versions/3.4.3/topics/splines-package) package that does the heavy lifting for us.

```
library(splines)

mydata <- read.csv(...)

myspline <- smooth.spline(x = mydata$x, y = mydata$y
                          , lambda = 8e-9 # optim 8.332658e-11
                          , cv = TRUE) 

xgrid <- sort(union(mydata$x
             , seq(from = min(mydata$x), to = max(mydata$x), by = 1))
             , decreasing = FALSE)

yhat_xgrid <- predict(myspline, x = xgrid)$y

plot(x = mydata$x, y = mydata$y, log = "x", ylim = c(0,1)
     , xlab = "x (log-scale)", ylab = "y"
     , col  = "lightblue", pch = 19)
lines(x = xgrid, y = yhat_xgrid, type = "l", col = "darkorange")
grid()
legend(...)
```

And we obtain this lovely plot.

[image: Smoothing spline $\lambda = 8 \cdot 10^{-9}$.]

The optimal values for $\lambda$ are $\hat{\lambda}^*_{\text{LOO}} = 8.33 \cdot 10^{-11}$ and $\hat{\lambda}^*_{\text{GCV}} = 5.81 \cdot 10^{-13}$. I like the one plotted: $\hat{\lambda}^*_{\text{Jim}} = 8 \cdot 10^{-9}$.

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/q/55363639/10698244 this post is referred to and it is asked for a `smoothing spline` implementation in Python. As it seems, there are different thoughts whether `UnivariateSpline` is a `smoothing spline` or not. Perhaps you could participate in the discussion there?

Answer (score 0):

In SciPy s-factor selection depends on the data scale. I use normalized s-factor in SplineCloud to avoid this ambiguity.

Basically, [SplineCloud](https://splinecloud.com/) provides an interactive version of a smoothing splines method but extends it to the parametric splines. You can reuse obtained curves in your code using API and a [client library](https://github.com/nomad-vagabond/splinecloud-scipy) for Python.

[image]